# Need to create a custom php page for a wordpress site having no theme folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WP, so please excuse if I ask anything silly.
I have WordPress site which have that created using builder and doesn't use page template of theme folder, everything is built on page builder. I also have other project that I've created on core php.

Is there a way to integrate Core PHP website with Wordpress website?

Comment: Its not possible wordpress have no theme folder

Comment: Actually the theme it contains is not what is running. Even if I delete that template inside theme folder, the site still runs cause it built on a page-builder.

Comment: Yes that's complete diffrent thing

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: what you want to integrate?

Comment: I have created a small project on php.

Comment: Lets say, wordpress website : example.com

php website : examplephp.com

All pages created in wordpress using page builder and now I want to integrate both. What kind of integration pass data from wordpress to php site? Design php page in wordpress?

Comment: I just need few form parameters that I can fetch through GET.

Comment: And I'll pass those parameters to my this php page which also should reside on the same server

Comment: pass php to wordpress or WP to PHP?

Comment: I have to pass this form parameters from wp to php page both are supposed to be on the same server and accessible through parent link like examplewp.com/myphppage.php

Comment: You can access wordpress in your root file

Comment: If you mean integration by same look and feel within the WordPress,
You can convert your core PHP website into functional WordPress theme. That is the best way.
Otherwise if it means linking the core site,
Just link the core PHP website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Page Template
Creating a page template is extremely easy. Create any new file in your theme (wp-content/themes/your-theme/my-custom-page.php) and start the file with a comment block like so:

```
<?php
    /*
        Template Name: My Awesome Custom Page
    */
    get_header();
?>

/*
    Code Here
*/

<?php
    get_footer();
?>
```

You need paste php code inside this template file. When you submit for then redirection action will be page with custom template page.

Reference :

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/

Video : 
https://youtu.be/1ZdHI8HuboA

Comment: Yes, but as I said earlier the pages of my wp sites are built using a page builder, that theme folder has no significance in it's working.

Comment: You mean I should create a template inside the theme folder?

Comment: @PK if you are using page builder, then you need to create a new page. And design the layout using blocks. To create new page go to `Pages` and `Add New`. Then design the page as you want. Ex: if it is WP Bakery Builder, it has so many options to create your own template design. No need to follow above scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your input @user2584538 I have already got it working the above way.

Comment: @PK good to hear it is working. If you like to proceed in above mentioned way it is better to use it via a Child Theme. Otherwise once theme update is there, you'll miss all the stuff. Please follow for more on Child Theme https://nerodev.com/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-wordpress/

Comment: @user2584538 I see. This is really important.